# make floating divs continue to stack to the right

Tags: css, css-float, floating

I have a parent div `form-group`, and inside form-group there multiple floating divs.

Here's their css attributes:

```
.form-group {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.department { width: 10%; white-space: nowrap; float: left; }
.firstname { width: 10%; white-space: nowrap; float: left; }
.lastname { width: 10%; white-space: nowrap; float: left; }
.title { width: 15%; white-space: nowrap; float: left; }
.email { width: 15%; white-space: nowrap; float: left; }
.mobile { width: 15%; white-space: nowrap; float: left; }
.phone { width: 15%; white-space: nowrap; float: left; }
.fax { width: 15%; white-space: nowrap; float: left; }
.remark { width: 20%; white-space: nowrap; float: left; }
```

And here's how they are positioned:

```
<div class="form-group">

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="department"><input name="contact[][department]" type="text" value="<?php echo $contact['department']; ?>"></div>
    <div class="firstname"><input name="contact[][firstname]" type="text" value="<?php echo $contact['firstname']; ?>"></div>
    <div class="lastname"><input name="contact[][lastname]" type="text" value="<?php echo $contact['lastname']; ?>"></div>
    <div class="title"><input name="contact[][title]" type="text" value="<?php echo $contact['title']; ?>"></div>
    <div class="email"><input name="contact[][email]" type="text" value="<?php echo $contact['email']; ?>"></div>
    <div class="mobile"><input name="contact[][mobile]" type="text" value="<?php echo $contact['mobile']; ?>"></div>
    <div class="phone"><input name="contact[][phone]" type="text" value="<?php echo $contact['phone']; ?>"></div>
    <div class="fax"><input name="contact[][fax]" type="text" value="<?php echo $contact['fax']; ?>"></div>
    <div class="remark"><input name="contact[][remark]" type="text" value="<?php echo $contact['remark']; ?>"></div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton fl"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```

The parent div is given `overflow: auto;` and the summed width of the floating child divs exceeds 100%. So I was expecting that the floating child divs are stacked to the right, whereas the parent div shows a horizontal scroll bar to display the portion of child divs that go beyond 100%.

However, the child divs are stacked until the sum of width gets to 100%, and everything beyond 100% goes to the next line, like the following:

---

|  div 1 | |  div 2 | |  div 3 | |  div 4 | |  div 5 | |  div 6 | |  div 7 |

---

---

|  div 8 | |  div 9 |

---

How do I make all these 9 divs stacked to the right in one line?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floated elements break into new lines just like words inside a long line of text.

In order to prevent words from breaking into new line you add `white-space: nowrap` on the element. You can use the same technique but for this you must ditch floats and use `display: inline-block`.

```css
.form-group {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.form-group > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
}
/* not relevant */

.form-group input {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="department"><input></div>
  <div class="firstname"><input></div>
  <div class="lastname"><input></div>
  <div class="title"><input></div>
  <div class="email"><input></div>
  <div class="mobile"><input></div>
  <div class="phone"><input></div>
  <div class="fax"><input></div>
  <div class="remark"><input></div>
</div>
```